# how to see all connected clients to a router/modem including linux and windows pcs

Tags: linux, windows, router, raspberry-pi, ip-address

I have an ADSL+2 router and a couple of computers including an ubuntu box, a raspberry pi and an old win7 pc. win7 and ubuntu are connected via wifi and raspberry pi via cable.

Now I'm wondring how to see the list all connected clients to my modem/router

Comment: Depends from where I guess. from Windows machine "arp -a" will show all connected devices to that router based on IP address and Mac address. The same information usually can be found on the modem/router DHCP log itself.

Comment: yup, arp is axactly what i needed, thanks. BTW i've found nmap to be a nice tool as it give a lot more extra informaton about hosts and available services on them

Comment: nmap (and the GUI front end zenmap) are very handy yes, but those are 3rd party application, hence why I didn't suggest it in the first place. nmap are also available on linux side if you need it that way.